# javascript for the production no working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i am currently working for the javascript on the production , when i have done the assets clean , this problem has occurred.
The application works well with the development mode but doesn't work on production 
please help.

Thanks

Atul Samage

Comment: Please go through asset pipeline in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production.

Comment: @prasanna ,Thanks for the reply but i have done the work on the asset pipeline already

Comment: then what is reason cleaning the assets, this will remove precompiled assets

Answer (score 0):

`rake assets:clean` deletes these precompiled files.

run `rake assets:precompile`  in your project folder

then you can commit these generated assets into the repository and proceed with deployment. No need to compile them on production machine.

Since precompilation is done in production mode only, no need to explicitly specify the environment.